# React-Redux: get difference on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using `mapStateToProps` in React.js to map an Array of Objects from the redux store to the React Component props. 
Then I am using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to listen to changes and update some graphics inside a canvas. I would like to find the object that has changed inside the array. The Object is rather big and nested.

In the redux chrome extension, you can see the "Data Difference" after each action. Is it somehow posible to access this "Data Difference" in React-Redux or do I need to implement that myself inside the `componentWillReciveProps()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React or Redux does not provide any such method.

You could you lodash to check for equality of two objects. Just loop over the array and compare each alternate object.

https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal